# Find the largest string such that 'a', 'b', 'c' are not continuos

Tags: string, algorithm

Q3:- We are given the maximum occurances of ‘a’, ‘b’ and ‘c’ in a string. We need to make the largest length string containing only ‘a’, ‘b’ and ‘c’ such that no three consecutive characters are same.

Ex:-

Input:- 3 3 3
Output:- abcabcabc
(There can be a lot of different outputs)

Input:- 5 5 3
Output:- aabbcaabbcabc

Comment: What is your question? The brute-force approach to this is not that complicated, but there may not be any such strings at all for sufficiently large differences in the three input values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use this algorithm:

As a preprocessing step, associate each letter (a, b and c) with its corresponding maximum frequency, so you can sort these character-frequency pairs as you wish.

Start with an empty string and perform the following actions in a loop:

- Sort the three letter-frequency pairs by decreasing frequency
- Pick the first pair from the sorted list and check its frequency. If it is zero, return the string
- If that selected character would violate the rule that the same character cannot repeat 3 times in a row, then pick the second pair from the sorted list instead and check its frequency. If it is zero, return the string
- Add the selected character to the string, and decrease its frequency.
- Repeat.

Here is an interactive implementation in JavaScript:

```js
function largestSequence(freq) {
    // Create a data structure the links a frequency with a letter (a, b or c)
    let chars = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        chars[i] = {
            freq: freq[i], 
            chr: "abc"[i]
        };
    }
    let s = "";
    while (true) {
        // Sort the three characters by decreasing frequency
        chars.sort((a, b) => b.freq - a.freq);
        let choice = chars[0]; // Choose the one with the highest frequency
        if (choice.freq === 0) break; // If no more character is avaiable, exit
        if (choice.chr + choice.chr === s.slice(-2)) {
            // If this character would violate the rule, choose the 
            // second one from the sorted list:
            choice = chars[1];
            if (choice.freq === 0) break; // If that character is not available, exit
        }
        choice.freq--; // Use this character
        s += choice.chr;
    }
    return s;
}

// I/O handling

let input = document.querySelector("input");
let output = document.querySelector("span");
input.oninput = function() {
    let freq = (input.value.match(/\d+/g) || []).map(Number);
    if (freq.length !== 3) {
        output.textContent = "(Please enter three integers)";
    } else {
        output.textContent = largestSequence(freq);
    }
};
input.oninput();
```

```html
Frequencies for a, b, and c: <input value="3 3 3"><br>
Longest string: <span></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Working Simple Solution with PQ

```
class Node {
    int count;
    char c;

    public Node(int count, char c) {
        this.count = count;
        this.c = c;
    }

    public void dec() {
        this.count--;
    }
}

public String solution(int A, int B, int C) {
    PriorityQueue<Node> queue = new PriorityQueue<>((a, b) -> b.count - a.count);
    if (A>0)
    queue.add(new Node(A, 'a'));
    if (B>0)
    queue.add(new Node(B, 'b'));
    if (C>0)
    queue.add(new Node(C, 'c'));

    StringBuilder ans = new StringBuilder();

    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {

        Node max1 = queue.poll();

        ans.append(max1.c); // a
        max1.dec();
        if (queue.size()>0){
            Node max2 = queue.poll();
            if (max1.count > max2.count) {
                ans.append(max1.c); //aa
                max1.dec();
                ans.append(max2.c); //aab
                max2.dec();
            }
            if (max2.count>0){
                queue.add(max2); // add back if count not zero
            }
        } else {
            if (max1.count>0){
                ans.append(max1.c); //aa and return as queue size is 1
                max1.dec();
                return ans.toString();
            }
        }
        if (max1.count>0){
            queue.add(max1); // add back if count not zero
        }
    }
    return ans.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// C++ implementation
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

bool compare(pair<int, char> a, pair<int, char> b) {
    // Sorting according to decreasing frequencies
    return a.first > b.first;
}

int main() {
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--) {
        // Making vector of pairs and mapping them with their characters v[0] is for "a", v[1] is for "b", v[2] is for "c"
        vector<pair<int, char>> v(3);
        cin>>v[0].first>>v[1].first>>v[2].first;
        v[0].second = 'a';
        v[1].second = 'b';
        v[2].second = 'c';
        string s;
        int total = v[0].first + v[1].first + v[2].first;

        while(1) {
            string prev = s;
            // sorting to bring the highest frequency element to front
            sort(v.begin(), v.end(), compare);
            if(v[0].first == 0)
                break;
            // when length of the string < 2
            if(s.length() < 2) {
                s += v[0].second;
                v[0].first -= 1;
                continue;
            }
            // when length of the string > 2
            int len = s.length();
            for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
                if(v[i].first > 0 and (s[len - 1] != v[i].second or s[len - 2] != v[i].second)) {
                    s += v[i].second;
                    v[i].first -= 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            // check if the state has not changed from the previous state even after checking for "a", "b" and "c"
            if(s.length() == prev.length())
                break;
        }
        cout<<s<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something similar using Priority Queue in C++. Adding my answer for someone looking for the answer in future.

```
int main() {
int a,b,c;
cin>>a>>b>>c;
priority_queue<pair<int,char>> pq;
pq.push({a,'a'});
pq.push({b,'b'});
pq.push({c,'c'});
string res="";
int x=5;
while(true){
    auto p=pq.top(); pq.pop();
    if(p.first==0){
        break;
    }
    if(res.length()==0){
        res+=string(min(p.first,2),p.second);
        p.first-=min(p.first,2);
        pq.push(p);
        continue;
    }
    int len=res.length();
    if(len>=1 && res[len-1]==p.second){
        auto p2=pq.top();
        pq.pop();
        if(p2.first==0){
            break;
        }
        res+=string(min(p2.first,2),p2.second);
        p2.first-=min(p2.first,2);
        pq.push(p2);
    }else{
        if(p.first==0){
            break;
        }
        res+=string(min(p.first,2),p.second);
        p.first-=min(p.first,2);
    }
    pq.push(p);
}

cout<<res<<endl;
}
```